# emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

i need to send some photos to my emulator gallery so that i can store them in db. due to this i need to run the following command in my android studio Terminal:

emulator -avd Pixel_3a_XL_API_30
running this command will stuck by this:

emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
i found this code in my google searches

%android_home%/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_3a_XL_API_30 -port 5554 -no-audio -no-boot-anim & %ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device

but it didnt work as well.
may i need to say that i have no microphone on my computer. should i have one?

operation always stopped showing "System UI isnt responding" on the emulator and as i said "emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App" on the terminal